# run a function with each possible combination of input variables

Tags: r

Is it possible to run every possible combination of values, between a certain range, through a function in R? For example, say that I have four variables

```
x1 = seq(from = 0.1, to = 35, by = 0.1)
x2 = seq(from = 0.1, to = 35, by = 0.1)
x3 = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 0.1)
x4 = seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 1)
```

and want to input them into a function:

```
kk <- my.func(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

My question: Is it possible to combine every possible combination of each value in the four variables into the function? For example:

```
kk <- my.func(x1 = 0.1, x2 = 0.1, x3 = 1, x4 = 1)
kk <- my.func(x1 = 0.1, x2 = 0.2, x3 = 1, x4 = 1)
```

and so on...

I realize that this will lead to a very large number of iterations but I would still like to see a way it can be done.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on the function you are using. Did you know about `combn` ? help(combn) will show some examples.

Comment: Probably something similar to `apply(expand.grid(x1, x2, x3, x4), 1, function(x) my.func(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))`

Comment: Are you aware that in the example you provided you'll have over 2 billions of possible combinations of the input arguments? Anyway, if `my.func` is vectorized over each argument, `do.call(my.func,expand.grid(x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3,x4=x4,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=FALSE))` will do the trick. Otherwise, see @DavidArenburg comment.